# Confused about binding chord data to ribbon path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In referencing this chord diagram example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006

The following block sets up the ribbon:

```
var ribbon = d3.ribbon()
    .radius(innerRadius);
```

But then later in the code `ribbon` is then used in a way I can't understand:

```
g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "ribbons")
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(function(chords) { return chords; })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", ribbon)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.target.index); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d3.rgb(color(d.target.index)).darker(); });
```

How is it that `.attr("d", ribbon)` knows how to pass in the chord data to ribbon? Is this just part of D3 magic that I have to just remember?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `d3.chord()` computes the layout of the data. It's important to note that, in d3, "layout" has a different meaning of layout in data visualisation: here, layout has to do with preparing the data to create a given chart (not the visual "layout" of the chart).

Basically, `d3.chord()` takes your data matrix and creates another data matrix with a bunch of starting angles and ending angles, associating sources to targets.

After `d3.chord()` modifies the data, they are passed to `d3.ribbon()`. `d3.ribbon` is the real path generator, creating the actual path that will be painted in the SVG. How does it knows the data? You have previously bounded the modified data to your group:

```
.datum(chord(matrix));
```

That's the data passed to `d3.ribbon()`.

According to the API, `d3.ribbon()`...

> ...generates a ribbon for the given arguments. The arguments are arbitrary; they are simply propagated to the ribbon generator’s accessor functions along with the this object [...] with the default settings, a chord object expected.